# How to use windows changepassword event in visual c++

Tags: windows, events, visual-c++, gina

i am using visual c++ to develop a sas(clt+alt+del) changepassword function...

so i have a button in my form...

if i will click the button,i want to display the change password dialogbox and process that function...

how can i use or invoke or call that changepassword event?

Thanks in advance
monu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keit Brown has written very good [articles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163786.aspx) about Gina. You'll find the answers regarding SAS in them.

Comment: But note that they only apply to Windows XP/2003.  Vista and later no longer use GINA.

Comment: Yes I know. From the question asked I supposed (since it is not mentioned) that the platform is XP/2K3 (since it is about implementing SAS).

Comment: i too know that mox..now i need,how to gina invoke or call the change password DIALOG BOX?...I WANT TO KNOW THE FUNCTION OR EVENT NAME OF CHANGE PASSWORD AND HOW CAN I USE THAT...THANKS IN ADVANCE SONU

Comment: WlxChangePasswordNotify (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa380550(v=vs.85).aspx)